# Solidity Error: Error: expected array value

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, javascript

I'm pretty new and learning along the way but I'm getting a Solidity error, no matter what I try I'm getting this error. Not sure what I should to fix.

Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)

```
function uri(uint256 _tokenId)
    public
    pure
    override
    returns (string memory)
{

function setURI(string memory newuri) external onlyOwner {
    _setURI(newuri);
}

function pause() external onlyOwner {
    _pause();
}

function unpause() external onlyOwner {
    _unpause();
}


function mint(uint256 id, uint256 amount)
    external
    whenNotPaused
    payable 
{
    require(msg.value == _prices[id], "Insufficient funds.");
    require(_supplies[id] >= amount, "Can not mint anymore");
    _mint(msg.sender, id, amount, "");
    _supplies[id] -= amount;
}


function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
    external
    onlyOwner
{
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        require(_supplies[ids[i]] >= amounts[i], "Can not mint anymore");
    }
    _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
}

function _beforeTokenTransfer(address operator, address from, address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
    internal
    whenNotPaused
    override(ERC1155, ERC1155Supply) 
{
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(operator, from, to, ids, amounts, data);
}

function setPrice(uint256 id, uint256 price) 
    external
    onlyOwner
{
    _prices[id] = price;
}

function setBatchPrices(uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory prices)
    external
    onlyOwner
{
    require(ids.length == prices.length, "Incorrect fields.");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        _prices[ids[i]] = prices[i];
    }
}

function getPrice(uint256 id) external view returns(uint256) {
    return _prices[id];
}

function getSupply(uint256 id) external view returns(uint256) {
    return _supplies[id];
}

function setSupply(uint256 id, uint256 supply) 
    external
    onlyOwner
{
    _supplies[id] = supply;
}

function setBatchSupplies(uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory supplies)
    external
    onlyOwner
{
    require(ids.length == supplies.length, "Incorrect fields.");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        _supplies[ids[i]] = supplies[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function are you calling? What parameter are you using? From the error message one of the parameter isn't valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'm trying to deploy a test run, the question then is what parameter is causing the error.

Comment: You haven't provided any detail that could be used to reproduce the problem. The issue isn't in the contract, but in the way it is deployed or initialized.

Comment: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";

contract Gabcoin is ERC1155, Ownable, Pausable, ERC1155Supply {
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _prices;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _supplies;

Comment: constructor(uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory prices)
        ERC1155(
            "http://arweave.net/F-vNncRtEDQADLijhtpINmObAprB0saDk9zj1CKMqa4/cloud{id}.json"
        )

        
    {
        require(ids.length == prices.length, "Incorrect fields.");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            _prices[ids[i]] = prices[i];
        }

Comment: Please, edit the question to add more details or the contract code.

Comment: Thanks it will only deploy if I switch to Metamask.